# HBA/JBOD SAS/SATA controller

Tags: hard-disk, sata, raid-controller

I'm looking for 16+ ports sata 3.0 controller for disks already initialized from Windows 10 (with GPT and NTFS volume) for pcie 3.0 motherboard, and I want to access to the data without any change (no other initialization for formatting).

I found [sata controllers dedicated to chia farming](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/1005003164217007.html), can they be used for JBOD also ? Which one do you recommend ?

Will their reliability be significantly different from a Broadcom controller ? Also there are no certification or norm: is it critical ? No MTBF: what should I expect ? The Broadcom 1500-16i for instance has 5 Mhours MTBF !

Answer (score 0):

I think Chia farming is JBOD, but the speed of that controller is really low, since it only uses one lane. My reccommendation is to look for a controller with about 1 lane for 4 SATA ports for maximum performance. I don't know if those exsist, but now you know what to search for.

Comment: Instead of  "speed is really low" can you provide a value ? There is also 12 ports pcie 4x !

Comment: 1GBps for all SATA ports combined

Comment: 12 ports 4 lanes should be good

Comment: OK. You want to update you answer with new details. Not a word about reliability and norms ?

Comment: SATA is SATA, PCIe is PCIe, and I don't know if there is much more

Comment: The implementation (what chip, which technology) and the environment (which temperature, etc) are important for reliability. SATA, SAS, pcie are norms and protocols and don't provide anything about reliability.

Comment: True, but those are not in the specs usually

Comment: Yes it is, for most industrial or middle/high end PSU, HBA and RAID adapters, HDDs , even fans etc.